# Trouble modifying axis domain in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization, axis

I'm trying to add a y-axis with domain [0, 500] to a canvas by calling the d3.axisRight() function as follows:

```
 var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, 500])
   .range([height, 0])

 var svgWithYaxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .call(d3.axisRight(yscale).ticks(10));
```

However, the axis does not show up and I get the following message, "Error: invalid format: ,.-1f". This only happens when I modify the domain to a large number [0, 500] here. d3.axisRight() works fine when I leave the domain as default, or when it's a lower number (~100). Why am I getting this error? How do I get my y-axis to appear with a domain greater than [0, 500]?

Comment: This problem seems to go away when I comment out a library I was using: 
http://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.45.min.js